# Conclusions from derivative

Tags: derivatives

Suppose f is continuously differentiable on [a,b] and f(a)=2 and $|f'(x) \leq 0.3|$ for all x. What can you say about f(b)?

The only result I could get was $\frac{f(b)-2}{b-a} \leq 0.3$ by the mean value theorem, which is not insighful. What else can be done here?

Comment: hint: try rearranging and finding out what $f(b)$ could be.

Comment: Hmm, what I have here is 3 unknowns, $f(b) \leq 0.3(b-a)+2$

Comment: You can find an interval where $f(b)$ lies in it.

Comment: Is the expression I have above the right bound? How would I go from this to an interval?

Comment: It is not the right bound. We need absolute value signs.

Comment: From the MVT we have $\frac{|f(b)-2|}{b-a}\le 0.3$. This can be rewritten as $2-(b-a)(0.3)\le f(b)\le 2+(b-a)(0.3)$.